# How to run mysqldump under XAMPP on Mac OS

Tags: macos, path, xampp, mysql

I want to run the `mysqldump` command in Mac OS, I am able to find the location of the file as "/Application/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin".

But don't know how to exec the same from command prompt, as it says command not find, by simply typing it and executing it from the prompt/

Answer (score 3):

The trick on *NIX systems when executing things is that you have to tell the shell exactly where the file is, or it must be in your `$PATH`.

This should work:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysqldump
```

This would also work:

```
 cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/
 ./mysqldump
```

If you want to make it so you can just type the command without giving the location, add it to your PATH variable:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
```

And then just run it!

```
mysqldump
```

Answer (score 0):

Also on Mac you can simply drag and drop the file from finder right into the terminal. This will automatically type the path for you.